# RavenDB Embedded in the Cloud

Tags: ravendb

Can you embed a RavenDB database in an MVC application that is hosted on Azure.
Ideally one could still access the management studio as well.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm attaching here the answer from the support email.

Yes, you can. Here are the steps:

1. Download the https://www.nuget.org/packages/RavenDB.Database/3.0.30115 package
2. Setup like this:

   var store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore
   {
       DataDirectory = "Data",
       UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true,
           Url = "http://localhsot:8080",
   };
3. Make sure to open the port in the firewall on Azure.
4. Access the studio using the server IP and port, as 11.22.33.44:8080

Comment: I don't believe this is possible as an Azure Web site that is based on Paas you cannot access any port. For that you need a Virtual Machine in which case embeddig RavenDB is not necessary anyway.

Comment: @user2981411 Yeah, Azure Web Apps don't allow configuring ports. Therefore, you won't be able to access the Studio like that. But, you can still run RavenDB embedded; you just won't be able to access the embedded Studio. If that's a show-stopper for you, you'll need to use an Azure virtual machine or some other cloud service that lets you open ports.

Comment: @Judah Then how would you manage your databases without a management Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is possible.
Note that this require a license.

Comment: No problem to buy a license. But how does one actually achieve it. There are lots of stuff on the net but all different and no clear documentation. Any chance of pointing us in the right direction when a site is hosted on Azure. Can we test it ? Many Thanks